# Click / MouseClick events never reach my WinForms UserControls

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, mouseevent

I have the following situation (simplified): In a WinForms Form, I have a GroupBox. Inside it are some UserControl_A objects, each of which contains several UserControl_B objects (both being derived from UserControl, of course).

I have a ContextMenuStrip for the GroupBox which is working fine with each right click, regardless whether on any UserControl_A/B object or the GroupBox background itself.

But I also need to process left clicks. Handling the Click and MouseClick events of the GroupBox is working, but only on the background. As soon as the pointer is inside a UserControl_A or UserControl_B object, nothing happens. I have tried to handle the Click and MouseClick events of both UserControl classes, but the handlers are never called at all.

Any hints what is going wrong here? Or how one can debug such an event handling problem?

Thank you very much in advance,
Stefan

Addition: I have now made a completely new, stripped-down project to explore the situation, and everything works fine. So how can I detect what's going wrong with my real project?

Comment: Hi Stefan, maybe you can show us some code of the onClick/onMouseDown...-methods of your UserControls.

Comment: There aren't any. I only have added UserControl_A_Click etc. delegates to the events. In the delegates, currently only a debug message is printed. -- Have you seen my addition? It seems it's not the mechanism itself but something inside my project is wrong. I already searched for all "click" strings in the code... nothing suspicious.

Comment: OK, this was my own fault. Sorry for wasting your time.

The reason was quite simple: Inside my UserControls I had other controls such as a docked TableLayoutPanel and some Labels. Mouse event handlers in the UserControl class never get any events because they are propagated into the inner controls. Hooking the delegate functions there works... :-)

Perhaps this can help people having a similar problem.

**Question answered. I'm not yet allowed to answer my own question here, will try to make good for that as soon as possible**

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your `UserControls` as child control to `GroupBox`:

```
groupBox.Controls.Add(yourUserControl); // correct way
```

in this type, right click works for all child of your parent control (GroupBox).

```
form.Controls.Add(groupBox);
form.Controls.Add(yourUserControl); // wrong way
```

Answer (score 0):

you put Mouse event in UserControl_A (i think it's class inherits Control)
the event will trigger when Mouse (over, down, etc.......) on that(UserControl)
when you on (your GroupBox ) the events blong to the groupBox